# Invalid VM runtime specified: php55 Google Appengine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml, google-managed-vm

I am trying to upload php code to the google app engine but I get this failure notice during the upload:

```
me@big-bite: $ appcfg.py -A my-hello-world -V v1 update ./
09:36 AM Application: my-hello-world (was: myapp); version: v1 (was: None)
09:36 AM Host: appengine.google.com
09:36 AM Starting update of app: my-hello-world, version: v1
09:36 AM Getting current resource limits.
09:36 AM Scanning files on local disk.
09:36 AM Scanned 500 files.
...
09:36 AM Scanned 6000 files.
09:36 AM Scanned 6500 files.
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
**Invalid VM runtime specified: php55**
--- end server output ---
```

Here is my app.yaml code:

```
application: myapp
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
vm: true

runtime_config:
  document_root: web
```

Thanks,
Pete.

Comment: This code comes from a Google repository: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) say

> The flexible environment includes native support for Java 8 / Servlet 3.1 / Jetty 9, Python 2.7 and Python 3.4, Node.js, and Go.

So no php. If you want to use php you will have to

> Developers can customize these runtimes or provide their own runtime, such as Ruby or PHP, by supplying a custom Docker image or Dockerfile from the open source community.

Comment: PHP is allowed and this is the code directly from the examples: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/quickstart#helloworldphp also  there are other examples: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appref that use php55

Comment: Also this entire example it PHP and it works fine: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/quickstart#download_the_hello_world_app

Comment: This code comes from a google repo on using php: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php

Comment: @hep those links also say you need a Dockerfile, do you have that configured? see https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/hello-world#configuring_the_app_engine_flexible_environment

Comment: Why did my other deployment work without one? And the other examples don't have a Dockerfile.

Comment: @hep were the other deployments also flexible environments? E.g. `vm: true`

Comment: Also I believe it should be `runtime: php` without 55

Comment: It still fails without the 55 as well. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear up some confusion here :)

`runtime: php55` only works on App Engine *standard*.  This does not run your code on a VM, rather runs in the App Engine standard sandbox.  It means you get a free tier, scale to 0, and App Engine APIs - but it also means no PHP 7.0 support, no composer support, and sandboxed APIs.

`runtime: php` only works on App Engine *flexible* - which is what you're using when you set `vm: true`.  It means you get to use PHP 7.0, Docker, and Composer - but it also means no free tier, no scale to 0, and no App Engine APIs.

The guide at https://cloud.google.com/php assumes you're using App Engine Flexible.  It really depends on what you're trying to build :)